# Asserting in Ruby on Rails - Is There a Simple Way to Do So?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing

I'm working on a rails project where I have a function which has to pass a lot of tests (hundreds\thousands calls to the function in it's unit test). I'm just looking for an easy way to assert the result (for example assert(class.foo(params)>0.6, true) to test foo's result is bigger than 0.6), and maybe have it print the line of the tests which didn't pass.

I'm used to this kind of unit testing from C\C++ programming, but from looking up online for a similar solution in rails I came up with gems like "MiniTest" where I have to encapsulate each assertion in a function (def \ assertion \ end), which triples the code's length and makes the whole process sisyphic and the code unreadable.

The bottom line:
I'm looking for a way to create a new instance of my class, i = my_class.new,
followed by many assertion: assert(i.foo(params)<0.6, true). If a test fails, it would be nice to be notified about the exact line.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about MiniTest, but RSpec (another popular testing framework) has the ability to aggregate errors. So you no longer have to adhere to the "one assertion per spec" rule. For example:

```
RSpec.describe 'my big function' do
  it 'does some stuff' do
    expect(foo(params)).to be > 0.6
    expect(bar(params)).to be < 0.4
  end
end
```

In case of multiple failures, you'll get a detailed report, pointing to exact lines with failed expectations.

Comment: Hi Sergio, thanks for replying.
I should have mentioned but I can't use RSpec because where I work it's configured to wipe the database it used after the test, which doesn't suit my needs. I could copy the database I use to a temporary location and then use RSpec on it, but that takes too much time. Changing the RSpec configuration isn't possible without causing a huge headache for me and my co-workers (they rely on this configuration).
Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

For minitest you can do multiple assertions in a check like this

```
require 'test_helper'

class ListTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  context "test my object" do
    setup do 
      @my_object = MyObject.new
    end

    should 'be greater than .6 and title equal to blah' do
      assert @my_object.value > 0.6
      assert_equal @my_object.title, 'blah'
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Hi Martin,
Using setup forces a new object to be created each function\"should" block, but I need the same object to be used in all of the tests (created once at the beginning). I remember looking it up and couldn't find an option to do so within the MiniTest framework.
I didn't know about the many assertions per "should" thing, do you know by any chance if the report afterwards would point to the exact line\assertion which failed?
Thanks!

Comment: @BenLiderman: in this setup it'll stop at first failure and won't proceed further, I think.

Comment: @BenLiderman it will list the exact file and line number in the results. It will break out of a should after it hits the first failure. You could try moving the setup outside of the context, but I think it still creates a new object each time. You could try persisting it to the db at the end of each should and then reloading.